# Travis CI. NetworkingError: CERT_UNTRUSTED error between Node.js and AWS S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, travis-ci

The setup.

I'm on Node.js using the aws-sdk npm module. I have an AWS bucket on S3 and the associated access and keys. The keys are in my .travis.yml file. I'm trying to test out saving an image up to my S3 bucket from my Node.js app.

The interesting thing... it's been working for a LONG TIME on Travis, then a few days ago it just stopped working with this error:

```
  message: 'CERT_UNTRUSTED',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'chyld-evernode-test.s3.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: Sat Dec 20 2014 18:35:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Now, it STILL works just fine on my LOCAL box and it also still works after deploy to HEROKU. My guess is something just happened on Travis which is causing my tests to fail.

Ideas?

Comment: I ran into the same issue after I installed the latest version of Node (v0.10.34). Uninstalling Node and installing an earlier version (v0.10.31) resolved it for me.

Comment: They released a patched version as well v0.10.35, which i downloaded and confirmed fixes the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like this is a known problem with 0.10.34:

- [node v0.10.34 causes untrusted cert errors](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8894)
- [src: re-add 1024-bit SSL certs removed by f9456a2](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/8904)

From the second link:

> this fixes a problem where connecting to AWS services
>   would report an untrusted cert error.

[From an issue in the knox repo](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/264):

> Solution: downgrade to v0.10.33

Comment: It works! I explicitly mentioned Node version 0.10.33 in my .travis.yml file and now the CERT_UNTRUSETED error is gone!

Comment: Works for me as well. This guide was helpful if you're not sure what's the best way to downgrade: http://www.websector.de/blog/2011/12/15/quick-tip-node-how-to-downgrade-node-js-on-os-x/

Comment: Seems to be fixed now in v0.10.35

Comment: thats work for me! I try using the version 0.10.33 and 0.10.35 the latest version is very recommended. An the best its work =D